# How to get all attribute and method names of an instance/class without using dir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes `__dir__()` [is overloaded](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) and just a subset of attributes is returned by `dir()`. Is there a way to show all existing attributes/methods of an instance or class by ignoring the overloaded `__dir__()` method?

For example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    pass
...
>>> Foo.__qualname__
'Foo'
>>> '__qualname__' in dir(Foo)  # I would expect this to evaluate to True
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling the overloaded `__dir__` you can call `object.__dir__`:

`'__qualname__' in object.__dir__(Foo)` returns `True`